# Query runs for too long

Tags: mysql, select

I have a select query that should return a result with about 200 rows from 3 tables:

- `wb_mod_deposit_out` - 700.000 rows
- `wb_mod_deposit` - 100.000 rows
- `from_generale_java` - 1200 rows.

The query is:

```
SELECT 

    DATE(a.created) AS DATA_MANCANTE, a.stagione, 
    c.status, a.modello, a.commessa, a.qnt_prod, 
    a.fabrica, a.CODE, a.color, a.measure, 
    ROUND(a.qnt,2) AS qnt_not_enough, 
    a.dist_base, b.qnt AS qnt_dept, 
    DATE(a.created) AS DATA_PRELIEVO, 
    C.`DATA_PREV_INI_TAG`, C.`DATA_PREV_INI_CONF` 

FROM

 wb_mod_deposit_out a,

 (SELECT CODE, color, ROUND(SUM(qnt),2) AS qnt 
  FROM wb_mod_deposit 
  GROUP BY CODE, color
 ) b, 

 from_generale_java C 

WHERE
      a.TYPE = 2 
  AND a.code = b.code 
  AND a.color = b.color
  AND b.qnt <= 0
  AND A.modello = C.MODELLO
  AND A.COMMESSA = C.COMMESSA
  AND A.STAGIONE = C.STAGIONE;
```

It takes about 2 min to return the result.

I have found a way to check myself with EXTEND:
https://www.slideshare.net/phpcodemonkey/mysql-explain-explained

Comment: It would help if you added the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT ...;` to the question and also the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE ...;` for the 3 tables. You probably need some indexes.

Comment: Also add the version of MySQL.

Comment: Thanks to all - i was using wrong indexes. "EXPLAIN" helped me to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `qnt <= 0` inside as a `HAVING` (*not* `WHERE`).

Use `JOIN ... ON ...` instead of `FROM a,b WHERE a...=b...`

Add the following composite indexes:

```
a: INDEX(type, code, color)
b: INDEX(code, color, qnt)
c: INDEX(modello, commessa, stagione)
```

Comment: Thanks. The first thing i was doing wrong is that i didn't had indexes on my columns.

Comment: @ValeriuChirica - Indexes are very important for performance.  Read my [_Cookbook_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) for more tips on indexing.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would try to make this faster, is to move the `b.qnt <= 0` filter closer to the `wb_mod_deposit` table as a `WHERE` or `HAVING` filter:

```
SELECT
    DATE(a.created) AS DATA_MANCANTE, a.stagione,
    c.status, a.modello, a.commessa, a.qnt_prod,
    a.fabrica, a.CODE, a.color, a.measure,
    ROUND(a.qnt,2) AS qnt_not_enough,
    a.dist_base, b.qnt AS qnt_dept,
    DATE(a.created) AS DATA_PRELIEVO,
    C.`DATA_PREV_INI_TAG`, C.`DATA_PREV_INI_CONF`

FROM
    wb_mod_deposit_out a

   ,(SELECT CODE, color, ROUND(SUM(qnt),2) AS qnt
     FROM wb_mod_deposit
     WHERE qnt <= 0 --try filtering early here...(test this version!)
     GROUP BY CODE, color
     --HAVING ROUND(SUM(qnt),2) <= 0  -- ...or here.
    ) b

   ,from_generale_java c

WHERE
      a.TYPE = 2
  AND a.code  = b.code
  AND a.color = b.color
  AND a.modello  = c.MODELLO
  AND a.COMMESSA = c.COMMESSA
  AND a.STAGIONE = c.STAGIONE;
```

Comment: If `b.qnt` values to be `SUM`med can be positive or negative, then this will pull anything with at least one negative or 0 `qnt`, even if the sum of all the `qnt`s would be positive. I think you need to go with the `HAVING` (and probably `HAVING ROUND(SUM(qnt),2) <= 0`, since column aliases can't usually be used except in the `ORDER BY` clause of a query).

Comment: RDFozz, you're totally right about both points. I thought of the 1st one right at the end and added the `HAVING` clause just before I posted the answer, without testing. That'll teach me! Thanks, and post fixed!